# About AWS SES using Java Api

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ses, java

I am new AWS user.

I want to use aws SES feature using java api.

When i tried to execute sample SES code of EC2 java api then it gives me following exception:-

"**Status Code: 400,
 
AWS Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService, 

AWS Request ID: 191f7c11-8652-11e2-be1c-6dd0975de4df, 

AWS Error Code: RequestExpired, 

AWS Error Message: Request timestamp: Wed, 06 Mar 2013 01:06:01 GMT expired.  

It must be within 300 secs/ of server time.**"

Why this exception comes?
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/) have several posts approaching this issue. Please have a look at [this specific thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=222908&#222908).
In general, your server might be out of sync with UTC, and Amazon servers are not accepting your requests because of a much different timestamp.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.

Is there any other way to send emails using Amazon services ?

Comment: The alternative to SES is setting up an EC2 instance with a Postfix, Sendmail, etc. IMHO, SES is much more scalable and easier to use, and might prevent you a couple of headaches.